# Prove that $(A\cap B)\cup(B\cap C)\cup(C\cap A)=(A\cup B)\cap(B\cup C)\cap(C\cup A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have used distributive law and absorption law combined but no result.

I have tried to complement the LHS to intersect with the RHS, and if we get the empty set then they are equal.

But none of the attempts helped me prove this.

Comment: Try a proof by Venn diagram as a last resort. If you don't like that, just enumerate all 8 cases of membership to a,b,c and show that both sets are equal in each case.

Comment: far more interesting, $\cup_{cyclic} A\cap B = \cap_{cyclic} A\cup B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said, you can always prove things like this with Venn diagrams, truth tables or Karnaugh diagram. In this case I'd say that would be the easiest way.

Otherwise you just use the distributive law together with absorbtion:

$$(A\cup B)\cap(B\cup C)\cap(C\cup A)
\\= ((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap B)\cup (B\cap C))\cap(C\cup A) 
\\= ((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\cup B \cup (B\cap C))\cap(C\cup A) 
\\= (A\cap B\cap C)\cup (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C) \cup (B\cap C) \cup
(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\cup (A\cap B) \cup (A\cap B\cap C)$$

Now you use absorbtion $(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B\cap C)= A\cap B$ and so you get rid of the $A\cap B\cap C$ terms and also remove duplicate terms (since $X\cup X=X$) and arrive at

$$(A\cup B)\cap(B\cup C)\cap(C\cup A)
= (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C) \cup
(A\cap B) $$

Comment: Hmm... after the first and second equal signs, the $($ are doubled, and the last sentence likely lacks a `$`

Comment: @FrenzyLi People really reading such long sequences of gibberish? Yes, I missed a closing parenthesis which I've added now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to convince myself of this equality as follows: $x$ is in the left hand side, iff $x$ is in at least two of the sets $A,B,C$ (by definition of union, and then intersection ). In that case it will be in all unions $A \cup B, B \cup C, A \cup C$, because to avoid that you have to miss at least two distinct sets. And if you're in all of the unions, you cannot avoid any pair of sets out of the three, so you're in at least 2 of them.